# Selective herbicides

Tags: botany, herbicide

There are several herbicides available that claim to kill lawn weeds but not the lawn grass. This seems amazing, to me. How does this work? How can a chemical be lethal to a broad range of plants, but not to grass? What’s the difference between weeds and grass?

Comment: I suggest you investigate C3 vs C4

Comment: Thanks. I see that wheat and rice are C3 plants. I’d guess that lawn grasses are similar to these?? But I also see that 95% of plants are C3, which suggests that most weeds are C3, too. Are you suggesting that lawn grasses are C4?

Comment: Those two articles are good but don't suggest any reason for selective action

Comment: From the second paper: “the underlying molecular mechanism of how auxinic herbicides selectively kill dicots and spare monocots is not understood yet”. So if dicots = weeds, and monocots = lawn grass, then I’m asking a question that didn’t have an answer in 2013.

Comment: Hmmm. To a lay-person like me, glyphosate seems like a good example of a herbicide that is *NOT* selective: as far as I can tell, it seems to kill everything. It certainly kills grass.